# Is it possible to consider the oscilloscope as an essential instrument?

Tags: electric-circuits, history, instrument

I recognize that the oscilloscope is a very useful instrument. But I would like to know what are the reasons why the oscilloscope is such a useful instrument in day-to-day scientific work. I would like to think that these reasons will be the same ones that motivated the design and creation of the first oscilloscopes.

I really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 3):

The oscilloscope lets you measure $y(t)$, for any variable $y$ in your system that you can convert to an electrical analog (in the original sense) signal. Even if $y(t)$ varies too fast to follow with your ordinary senses.

Comment: Concise! Don't forget that "trigger" function.